# Unable to leave abandoned project

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to remove my self from an abandoned project on VSO. It is showing up as a listed account:

[image: Account Listing]

In the user management screen I am unable to remove my self, I only have "Basic Access":

[image: User Management]

and of course, I am unable to delete the entire account:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here? I would like to get that account off my profile as it is no longer used, and will be using VSO quite regularly from now on.

Comment: Could you make another account that isn't linked to your normal account, transfer it to that account then remove this account.

Comment: Apologies for asking the bleeding obvious - who or which account is the owner of the project?  Shouldn't you be asking that person, or using that account, to perform this?

Comment: Haven't spoken to the actual owner in years, I thought being able to leave an account would be an obvious function but it does not seem to be the case. I am not the account owner, just a basic user that was added (don't even remember touching it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is an [issue raised for Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809773/visual-studio-online-cannot-remove-self-from-someone-elses-account) around this issue - the 'feature' to remove your self from accounts you do not own has not yet been implemented.